# Help with French Rebus

Tags: expressions

What is the berry and what does the cow say in this puzzle

[image: Puzzle Image]

> "Nous sommes abandonnés"

Comment: For the record, such a puzzle is called a "rébus".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That holly berry is the [*houx*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/houx/40544?q=houx#40452). The cow mooing is either *[meugler](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/meugler)/beugler/mugir* but the typical sound is [*meuh*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_d%27onomatop%C3%A9es_dans_diff%C3%A9rentes_langues#Vache_.28mugir.29) ! Spoilers ahead.

> N' - houx - seau - meuh - A - banc - dos - nez ! (*Nous sommes abandonnés* !)

Answer (score 3):

The berry is called "[Houx](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Houx)", and the cow says "meuh"
 (it doesn't say anything in particular, it's just the sound of a cow in French, same as "Moo" in English).

Answer (score 2):

Peut-être bien qu'il sgit de l'onomatopée désignant le meuglement des vaches : « **meuh** ». Ce qui correspond au son « **m** » du mot « **sommes** ».